# Scroll to a specific div that's not in view

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein, scrollto, scrolltop

I am trying to scroll to the top of a specific div container.  Currently my code is instead scrolling the page content into view. Anybody has an idea how what's wrong? : ) Here's the code:

```
var openItem;

var showBox = function(item) {
    item.removeClass("loading");
    var infoBox = $("div.test", item);

    // Resize box
    item.width(853);
    item.height(infoBox.outerHeight());

    // Reload Masonry
    $('#container').isotope('reLayout');

    // Insert close button
    $('<a href="#" class="close">Close</a>"')
        .prependTo(".test .content")
        .click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            close(item);
        });

    // Insert close button
    $('<a href="#" class="close">Close</a>"')
        .appendTo(".test .content")
        .click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            close(item);
        });

    // Fade in test box
    setTimeout(function () {
        testBox.fadeIn();

        // Scroll box into view
        $(document).scrollTo(item, 1000);
    }, 280);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is item? Like is it a jQuery object?

Comment: the jmasonry (isotope) boxes that will "resize" and unveal content.

Comment: If the scrolling isn't happening, try `$.scrollTo(item, 1000, function(){});`

Comment: the scrolling works perfeclty, the problem is that i have rows. each row has 4 boxes. so when i click box 2,3 and 4 it works perfectley and the scroll box into view method will scroll to the top of the unvealed content ( set by 280 at the bottom) but when i click the first box in each row, it scrolls waaay to far in the unvealed content, since it is jmasonry (isotope) and box 2,3 and 4 relayout beneath the box 1 so the 280 is exactly the right length but unfortunetley not for the first box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I see your problem.  Try replacing your `setTimeout` code with this:

```
// Fade in test box
setTimeout(function() {
    testBox.fadeIn(function() {
        // Scroll box into view
        $(document).scrollTo(item, 1000);
    });
}, 280);
```

The reason your original code wasn't working before was because when `$(document).scrollTo(item, 1000)` was called `item` was not visible yet, so `scrollTo` didn't know where the item was located.

**EDIT in response to comment with the code example:**

It looks like the bug you're seeing is *not* by the `showBox` function you posted above.  The problem is caused by elements with the class `showMe` getting hidden after the `scrollTo` function has been called.  Try hiding the `showMe` elements as soon as the user clicks them instead of fading them out.

Comment: Hi Xavi, thanks for your answer and your afford. the scrolling works perfectly, my problem is that it scrolls to deep into view. even when i set the 280 to 0. i have 4 boxes in a row. for box 2,3 and 4 it works perfectly and it scrolls to the top of the hidden content set with 280. it just doesn't work for box 1 since i work with jmasonry (isotope) box 2,3 and 4 rearrange beneath box 1 (visible content will be between box 1 and the rest of the boxes) when clicked and unvealing content. so the problem is just for the first box, the scroll into view won't scroll to the top but deep inside of it

Answer (score 2):

Scrolling to an item won't always work because Isotope uses CSS transforms for positioning, not `top/left`. You could disable transforms with `transformsEnabled: false`. Better yet, if you need to get the position of an item with Isotope, use [itemPositionDataEnabled](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#itempositiondataenabled).